# Prime Squares: $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $a,b,c,d,a+b+c+d$ are each between twin primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

[Edited since answer] I have an updated and more advanced version of the prime square in this post: [Prime Square: Updated Concept](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515549/prime-square-updated-concept)

Hello everyone! I would like some feedback on a new idea of mine.

It's called a Prime Square.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Prime Square]

- Definition: *Edit since answer* A Prime Square is composed of four numbers, each between a pair of Twin Primes (18, 18, 18, 18) AND the sum of all four numbers is also between a pair of Twin Primes(72).

The Prime Square has been found! 18+18+18+18=72

Comment: $6+30+42+102=180$ (before you edited)

Comment: So … none of the numbers is actually prime, and for large numbers it starts to look distinctly rectangular.  (-:

Comment: These combinations are fairly common. For sums < 2000 I get 13544 combinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you let numbers repeat, $618+2238+2238+2238=7732$ works.

If not, $6+2238+2688+3360=8292$.

If you want all numbers the same, $18+18+18+18=72$ is the smallest ($60$, $108$, and $150$ are the others that I found, up to 250).

Computed in Magma:

```
N := {i : i in [1..1000] | IsPrime(i-1) and IsPrime(i+1)};
{{a,b,c,d} : a,b,c,d in Numbers | a+b+c+d in Numbers};`
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Now that I know it's possible... is there one where all the numbers are the same? I imagine I'm asking because you have the mathematical engine and I don't...

Comment: Is there a way for me to learn the computational engine to find these values so I can avoid writing up questions?