# Super Prime Squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

[Major Revision 11/13/2017 1:00 AM]

[My original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514687/prime-squares-a-b-c-d-such-that-a-b-c-d-abcd-are-each-between-twin-pri) presented the concept of a "Prime Square". The conditions were obviously lacking as the user PM 2 Ring was able to discover 13544 combinations under 2000.

I have since updated the criterion to reflect a popular post I made in the past: [Sets of Prime and Composite Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491927/sets-of-prime-and-composite-numbers)

This is an example of the updated concept:

[image]

$ 24 + 36 + 42 + 120 = 222 $

$ 222 / 6 = 37 $

$ (37 + 24) = 61 ; (37 + 36) = 73 ; (37 + 42) = 79 ; (37 + 120) = 157 $

**Definition: Each corner represents the average of one of the four possible sets, with no set appearing more than once. If their sum (222) divided by 6 equals a prime, and furthermore that prime(37), when added to each of the four corners, equals four new primes (61, 73, 79, 157), then it's a Super Prime Square.**

The sets are as follows:

> We know that all primes are of the form $ 6k ± 1 $ with the exception of 2 and 3.
>
> We also know that **not** all numbers of the form $ 6k ± 1 $ are
>   prime.
>
> This leads to four distinct sets of pairs adjacent to a multiple of
>   six:
>
> 1. Twin Primes, Example: $ 5, 7 $ (prime followed by a prime)
> 2. Twin Composites, Example: $ 119, 121 $ (composite followed by a composite)
> 3. Prime-Composite, Example: $ 23, 25 $ (prime followed by a composite)
> 4. Composite-Prime, Example: $ 35, 37 $ (composite followed by a prime)

**Question: The challenge is to find the largest Super Prime Square such as [42, 24, 36, 120] 37; that when the solution (such as 37) is added to each of the four corners yields four new primes ( 79, 61, 73, 157)**

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try to find such numbers starting from a given prime p, then see if you can divide 6p into 4 distinct composite numbers all multiple of 6?

Comment: @user25406 It can't just be 4 distinct composite numbers because each of the four needs to belong to one of the four sets I described. In other words, each of the four needs to be represented, the set cannot repeat.

Comment: I think you should expound more.  Sounds interesting

Comment: Another Prime Square is 18 + 84 + 78 + 186 = 366 ; 366 / 6=61 ; 61 is Prime

Comment: Seems that we can get any prime $p\ge 31$ and that there are plenty of quartuples doing the job. Upto the prime $631$, there are multiple solutions (except for $p=31$)

Comment: The $5$ solutions for $p=37$ are : [12, 24, 66, 120]  37
[12, 54, 36, 120]  37
[18, 24, 36, 144]  37
[18, 48, 36, 120]  37
[42, 24, 36, 120]  37

Comment: And the $9$ solutions for $p=41$ are : [6, 24, 96, 120]  41
[6, 54, 66, 120]  41
[6, 84, 36, 120]  41
[12, 24, 66, 144]  41
[12, 48, 66, 120]  41
[12, 54, 36, 144]  41
[18, 48, 36, 144]  41
[42, 24, 36, 144]  41
[42, 48, 36, 120]  41

Comment: @lurker what do you mean by is there a sequence of numbers $31$ that fit this criterion?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the feedback! I've since updated the challenge!

Comment: @EnjoysMath My challenge has been updated to reflect recent revelations from feedback. I'm now only interested in the highest value of this new concept.

Comment: @lurker I suggest to name the desired prime-squares "super-prime-squares"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the PARI/GP code for the search of super-prime-squares (having the additional desired property) and an already large example.

```
? gef=0;while(gef==0,a=random([100,10^6]);while(1-(Mod(a,6)==0)*(isprime(a-1,2)=
=1)*(isprime(a+1,2)==1),a=random([100,10^6]));b=random([100,10^6]);while(1-(Mod(
b,6)==0)*(isprime(b-1,2)==0)*(isprime(b+1,2)==1),b=random([100,10^6]));c=random(
[100,10^6]);while(1-(Mod(c,6)==0)*(isprime(c-1,2)==1)*(isprime(c+1,2)==0),c=rand
om([100,10^6]));d=random([100,10^6]);while(1-(Mod(d,6)==0)*(isprime(d-1,2)==0)*(
isprime(d+1,2)==0),d=random([100,10^6]));p=vecsum([a,b,c,d])/6;if(isprime(p,2)==
1,if(isprime([a,b,c,d]+vector(4,j,p),2)==[1,1,1,1],gef=1)));print([a,b,c,d],"
",p,"     ",[a,b,c,d]+vector(4,j,p))
[155862, 377346, 449400, 511314]   248987     [404849, 626333, 698387, 760301]
?
```

Here an example with $10$-digit numbers (one of the sums has even $11$) :

```
[7930195380, 5831272896, 4808600274, 1846715928]   3402797413     [11332992793,
9234070309, 8211397687, 5249513341]
```

Comment: Thanks! Did they appear often or were the results scattered?

Comment: @lurker I only searched for large examples, so I have no clue how often they appear.