# Prime Polygon: Completed Concept

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> *I have made [two prior posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515549/super-prime-squares/2518018?noredirect=1#comment5201310_2518018) regarding this concept, and it has evolved thanks to feedback and further clarification from this
>   excellent community. I hope to provide a clear and simple presentation
>   of its completed form, along with a new challenge to those interested.*

**A Prime Polygon is defined as a [polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polygon.html) where:**

1. Each vertex is assigned a unique value that is a multiple of 6. (e.g. 24, 36, 42, 120)
2. The combined sum of all the vertices divided by 6 equals a prime number. (e.g. 37)
3. When each of the vertices is added to this prime (e.g. 37), they each generate a new prime number. (e.g. 61, 73, 79, 157)

**An example of a Prime Polygon:**

[image: Prime Polygon]

> **Question & Challenge:** Find a Prime Polygon with the largest number of vertices.

Comment: @peter Another challenge if you're able and willing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands now, arbitrarily large examples are trivial to find.

{6, 12, 30, 42, 96} make a pentagon.

{6, 24, 30, 36, 60, 66} make a hexagon.

{12, 18, 36, 60, 78, 90, 96, 102, 132, 138, 150, 162, 222, 258, 276, 
  312, 330, 336, 342, 378, 396, 420, 432, 468, 498, 510, 522, 540, 
  552, 582, 588, 600, 630, 696, 708, 720, 732, 762, 876, 918, 948, 
  990, 1050, 1110, 1146, 1158, 1182, 1236, 1272, 1308, 1380, 1422, 
  1470, 1482, 1488, 1506, 1512, 1518, 1548, 1566, 1578, 1590, 1602, 
  1638, 1650, 1662, 1716, 1728, 1740, 1746, 1776, 1788, 1806, 1830, 
  1848, 1860, 1926, 1932, 1950, 1980, 1986, 1992, 2016, 2028, 2040, 
  2052, 2082, 2100, 2112, 2118, 2136, 2142, 2148, 2160, 2178, 2262, 
  2268, 2280, 2292, 2358} make a 100-gon.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "trivial"? Would you change any of the conditions?

Comment: By trivial, I mean that one can find example for 5, then an example for 6, then think of a much larger number that would be remarkable in at least some way, come up with 100, and find _that_ many, all that despite not being a math genius and having other job to do. As for change, it's not that simple. Now it's trivial; you change one tiny detail, and it becomes provably unsolvable. You change another tiny detail, and it becomes equivalent to a known open question. You change yet another, and it becomes so complicated that nobody would look at it. Inventing good problems is a tricky business!